# Eevee & Cycles unable to render image despite no discernible changes to file

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am having a major difficulty in getting my file to render at all in both Eevee and Cycles. I have been using blender on and off for about 2 years and have never encountered an issue like this, though I am very much a novice.

I checked my compositing nodes, made sure my layers were set to render, and even tried copying the items from one file to another, all with the same result. It's not an issue with the lights either, as it is not rendering as a black image but as the PNG checkered grid which I am taking to mean as not being able to render anything at all. Cycles doesn't work either.

Initially, I did not run into any problems with rendering on Eevee for this file, but I can't pinpoint exactly what I changed to cause this error. I sent the files to another computer thinking it was an internal issue but the other computer was unable to render the file as well. I am still able to render other .blend files and I doubt it's the resolution size (as I've rendered files that were larger than this) so it's something specific to this file that is driving me up the wall. Everything still looks fine in the render viewport.

I would appreciate any insight or tips you all may have on this problem! I have been troubleshooting for the past two days without any leads. Thank you!

UPDATE: So turns out my issue was due to 3 remesh modifiers generating a massive amount of geometry. I still don't really know how I was able to render them with no issue the first couple of times, but I guess I will just have to work around it.

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file (only keep several objects)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Just updated; thanks for providing the link!

Comment: your file makes my Blender crash, I hope someone will be able to test it  :/

Comment: OMG so your comment actually made me double back and go through my objects again with a fine toothed comb...seems like I have a heinous amount of verts due to a couple of remesh modifiers in place. I removed them and the render worked as normal, albeit with messed up geometry!

Comment: ah ah it often happens

Comment: Thank you so much for indirectly helping me figure this out! hahaha